# Resize with ImageMagick with a maximal width / height

Tags: image, imagemagick, image-resizing

The command

```
imageconvert.exe in.jpg -resize 800x600 out.jpg
```

resizes the image so that it keeps original ratio, with maximum width of 800, and maximum height of 600 pixels. But if the image is smaller *both in width and height* (e.g. a 300x200 image), it will be enlarged to reach 800 or 600, and I don't want this.

**How to keep the same kind of resizing (when width > 800 or height > 600), but such that an image that is smaller *both in width and height* (e.g. a 300x200 image), will be untouched?**

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think you need the `>` flag on the `resize`. Let's create some images (one red 300x200, another blue 1000x500):

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:red   small.png
convert -size 1000x500 xc:blue large.png
```

Now convert them both to 800x600 with no flags:

```
convert small.png -resize 800x600 a.png   # 800x533
convert large.png -resize 800x600 b.png   # 800x400
```

Now with flags:

```
convert small.png -resize 800x600\> a.png # 300x200
convert large.png -resize 800x600\> b.png # 800x400
```

You may need a caret (`^`) rather than a backslash on Windows.

The various flags are explained in the documentation [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry). Thanks to @user1133275 for the suggestion.

Comment: Indeed! It's `-resize 800x600^>` on Windows.

Comment: @user1133275 Many thanks for the helpful suggestion - I have updated my answer.